# Localization in spartacus

Tags: internationalization, spartacus-storefront

Can anyone please let me know the library we need to import for cxTranslate. I am getting the below error in Spartacus Application

The pipe 'cxTranslate' could not be found!

Comment: I have added the below module in my customized module but still seeing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

just add the following line in your application module:

import { I18nModule } from '@spartacus/core';

[image]

[image]

Best regards,
Jerry

Comment: Thanks Jerry but I am facing one more problem. I want to override the OOTB translations in spartacus but it is not working. Below is the code snippet             
     ConfigModule.withConfig({
      i18n: {
        backend: {
          loadPath: './assets/i18n-assets/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
        },
        chunks: translationChunksConfig,
        resources:translations,
        fallbackLang: 'en'
      },
    } as I18nConfig),Please help

Comment: Hello there, for overriding OOTB translations, please refer to our document: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/#overwriting-individual-translations

Comment: Hi  Surya I have used the below snippet    and it worked                                                                                                       
      import { myCustomTranslationChunksConfig, myCustomTranslations } from './assets/translations/translations';
        providers: [
  
    provideConfig({
      i18n: {
        resources: myCustomTranslations,
        chunks: myCustomTranslationChunksConfig,
        fallbackLang: 'en'
      },
    } as I18nConfig)